# how can i convert array of objects to one object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to convert object1 to object2 dynamically because keys like apple and water and inside objects are not static.

```
const object1 = {
        apple:[
            {a:''},
            {b:''}
        ],
        water:[
            {c:''},
            {d:''}
        ]
    }
```

convert to this form:

```
object2 = {
    apple:{a:'',b:''},
    water:{c:'',d:''}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  `Object.entries` to iterate the key value pairs, then use `Object.assign` to merge the inner objects, and finally collect the generated pairs back into one object with `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const object1 = {apple:[{a:''},{b:''}],water:[{c:''},{d:''}]}

const object2 = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(object1).map(([key, arr]) =>
    [key, Object.assign({}, ...arr)]
  )
);

console.log(object2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const object1 = {
        apple:[
            {a:''},
            {b:''}
        ],
        water:[
            {c:''},
            {d:''}
        ]
}

let object={}
Object.keys(object1).forEach((item)=>{
 let obj={};
 object1[item].map((e)=>{
    obj={...obj,...e};
 });
 object[item]=obj; 
})

console.log(object)
```